# Update a Call procedure in tibco administration

Tags: tibco

I Created a procedure in oracle db and deployed it  in the  tibco administration.It gives exact output what i am expecting. My question is if i make any changes in that procedure( in db) ,how the changes will reflects to the tibco administration,..?

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with the terms so that everyone can understand your question. If I got it right, you created a BW application which calls an Oracle stored procedure and you deployed this application in TIBCO Administrator.

The impact of making changes to that procedure depends on the nature of the changes. As long as you don't alter its signature (name, input/output parameters and DB schema it belongs to), it shouldn't impact the behavior of your application. If you change its signature, however, your application will very likely generate errors that will be logged in the application's trace file (which you can view in TIBCO Administrator), unless caught/handled otherwise. You will then need to update your code in TIBCO Designer, rebuild the EAR file and redeploy it.

Comment: Thanking you for your suggestion and reply.Is there any alternative choice  to get the updated procedure in the administration except rebuilt the ear and redeploying it,..?